# Is there a max limit for file upload using Apache FileUpload API?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) . When I try to upload files greater than 40MB, its crashing. I'm trying to figure out the stacktrace, but meanwhile, is there any limit or any way to configure a limit for the FileUpload

I'm working on an already exisiting code, and I couldn't find any instance of

```
// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Set overall request size constraint
upload.setSizeMax(yourMaxRequestSize);
```

which, I found in another thread, is used to set the maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure upload settings by set maximum file size and maximum request size.

```
private static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE      = 1024 * 1024 * 40; // 40MB
private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE   = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

// sets maximum size of upload file
upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);

// sets maximum size of request (include file + form data)
upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is, MultipartRequestHandler.ATTRIBUTE_MAX_LENGTH_EXCEEDED is already set to true when a file above 40mb is uploaded, without configurig these

Comment: This is the ServletRequest attribute that should be set when a multipart request is being read and the maximum length is exceeded.